# Where is the C/C++ Standard Library in Android and iOS?

Tags: android, c++, ios, c

As far as I know one can can write apps on Android and iOS in C/C++, instead of Java and Objective-C.

Since both C and C++ rely upon their Standard Libraries, where and how the C/C++ Standard Library is implemented in such OSes? Is it part of something bigger like e.g. the Android NDK? If it isn't, can I use a different implementation if needed?

Comment: It probably comes with the compiler. Like Xcode for iOS.

Comment: Those libraries come with NDK C/C++ toolchains, and most likely are stuffed into the resulting .apk. Several implementations of C++ standard library are included, from which you can choose.

Comment: c and c++ library are different thing. C runtime library is a part of any Linux distribution, so android has to have it. I imagine, iOS is the same thing, since it is Unixy in nature. C++ is a different thing, and probably has to be a separate library inside .apk.

Comment: Read: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html

Comment: @SergeyA You seemed confused. The CRT and C library are two different things. You have different C libraries, like glibc, uClibc, and newlib which are platform independent. The CRT is platform-dependent. This is going to be a combination of the kernel and files provided by the compiler (see `crt0.o`, et al.) It is not Linux/Unix specific by any means, nor does it imply that Androis/iOS are forced to use the same CRT/C library.

Comment: On iOS with Apple’s tools (Xcode and an iOS SDK), the C standard library is part of general support libraries supplied with the system and rolled up into files integrated with the OS. Also, the compiler is very smart about some things, so some of your library calls may be replaced at compile time (e.g., `memcpy` might become move instructions, and `pow(x, 2)` may become `x*x`). You might be able to link with your own implementations of C library routines instead of Apple’s, but why would you want to? Everything you need should be present once you install Xcode with an iOS SDK.

Comment: There is no such option to write the entire Android application, in C/C++. The Android API and its class library are Java and for example to create the main Activity you have to create a Java object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several concepts at play here, I'm going to try to keep it brief. Android uses [Bionic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bionic_(software)) as its C library. It also lists [different C++ libraries](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html), however, they recommend you stick with libc++ (Clang) since they have stopped supporting libstdc++ (what they call gnustl) and STLPort is ancient. Now even though they call `libstdc++` the system runtime, for `libstdc++` in particular, the support library is called actually [libsupc++](http://wiki.osdev.org/Libsupcxx). In order to have exception and RTTI support, you need to implement/build this, which doesn't seem to be the case for Android.

For Apple, it's a different story. XCode is the IDE (not the compiler!) On old versions of Mac, they shipped an ancient version of GCC. There was a transition period where they used `llvm-gcc` and symlinked `gcc` to `clang`. Now the latest version of XCode only supports LLVM/Clang. By default, Mac uses libc++, but you can select libstdc++ if you prefer. Keep in mind that although Clang tries to be as ABI-compatible with GCC as possible, it's probably not wise to mix libraries compiled by libc++/libstdc++.

Can you use a different C library in your toolchain? Not easily. You would need to port the C library of choice (i.e, Newlib) to the platform which is not trivial. Further, you would need to build a cross compiler toolchain that not only targets that system but also uses the new library. You will have to look into people who have already done this for you.

Now even if it was easy, there really isn't a good reason to. More often than not you only want to swap out selective parts of the library, like `malloc`. Android in particular can use [jemalloc](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/jemalloc/) for example.